# Classic sci-fi anime, where mechs are launched by space shuttle like booster system to hotspots on earth

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I am looking to find the name of a series for which I had seen a few episodes quite a while back - say about 15 or so years back - on either Animax India or AXN (AXN India used to show some anime shows when it first started). It basically had the art style of classic mecha anime - think like Macross or older Gundam series or the first metal gear panic series. 
It was a more military-themed, United Earth possibly, where earth forces used to launch mech suits strapped to Space shuttle type booster rockets and fuel pods to possible hot spots or where the aliens were attacking(or bad guys?). I am not sure about the details of who the antagonists were in the series - but the mech plus booster rocket launch sequence stood out to me.
Any clues or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved if you went through the checklists here; [How to ask a good anime Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Reminds me of *Captain Earth*, but that's from the mid-2010s. I think Jacob C might be right; if there's any other details you can remember, please add them. Every little helps.

Answer (score 2):

Without further details narrowing it down, multiple mecha series probably match the question as it stands. One possibility is *Robotech* (the English language series which through editing and changed dialogue glued together the mentioned Japanese series *Macross* with a couple of other unrelated but stylistically similar anime series).

The "Shimada Enterprises SC-32 Roc Trans-orbital Transport Space Shuttle" seems like what you describe.

From [an entry on the site "Mecha Journal"](http://mechajournal.com/2016/05/shimada-enterprises-sc-32-roc-trans-orbital-transport-space-shuttle/) which in turn credits the ["Unofficial Robotech Reference Guide 2066 edition"](http://ptn.home.xs4all.nl/robotech.html):

> During the war with the Robotech Masters, these simple cargo shuttles were rapidly built and modified to carry mecha into combat.

Comment: *Gunbuster* also [had Mecha that spaceship *forms*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0vCY3I5yxo) but that doesn't quite match the question.